# Проверить если в папке(A),подпапка (B),если есть,то в файл выписать абсолютный путь этой подпапки(B)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как узнать если в папке подпапка,и как записать абсолютный путь подпапки в файл?

Answer (score 3):

Удобно [`pathlib` модулем](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) воспользоваться для этой задачи в Питоне 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('A') / 'B'
if path.is_dir():
    Path('путь подпапки.txt').write_text(str(path.absolute()))
```